# The entity type HashSet<Product> was not found when using RemoveRange

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

Using Entity Framework Core 3.1 I am deleting all products in a few baskets:

```
 IQueryable<baskets> baskets = _context.Baskets.Where(x => x.Value <= 10);

 _context.RemoveRange(baskets.Select(x => x.Products));
```

On RemoveRange command I get the error:

```
'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll: 
'The entity type 'HashSet<Product>' was not found. 
Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.'
```

I am able to create, update and delete one item.

The problem is only with `RemoveRange`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `x.Products` is a *collection* navigation property, hence `Select` returns collection of collections, while `RemoveRange` expects collection of objects (entity instances).

Simply replace `Select` with `SelectMany`:

```
_context.RemoveRange(baskets.SelectMany(x => x.Products));
```